# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4' e não consigo acessar o modulo bs4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Estou tentando importar o modulo bs4 em um código e toda vez que eu tento o seguinte erro é exibido

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
```

Teoricamente o modulo bs4 já foi instalado e quando eu executo no terminal o comando `pip install bs4` aparece a seguinte mensagem:

```
C:\Users\gabri>pip install bs4
Requirement already satisfied: bs4 in c:\users\gabri\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (0.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in c:\users\gabri\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from bs4) (4.9.3)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>1.2 in c:\users\gabri\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from beautifulsoup4->bs4) (2.2.1)
```

O modulo requests está funcionando e quando eu tento instalar ele dá a seguinte, mensagem. Estava tentando comparar com o modulo bs4 para ver se estavam instalados em locais diferentes mas não seguinte encontrar o erro

```
C:\Users\gabri>pip install requests
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\gabri\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (2.25.1)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in c:\users\gabri\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from requests) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\gabri\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from requests) (2020.12.5)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<5,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\gabri\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from requests) (4.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\gabri\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from requests) (1.26.5)
```

minha versão atual do python é essa:

```
Python 3.9.5
```

minha versão atual do pip é essa:

```
pip 21.1.2 from c:\users\gabri\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)
```

E esse é o código que estou tentando usar o comando e está dando erro:

```
import requests as r
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

try:
    result = r.get('https://www.google.com.br/search?q=Python')
    
except Exception as err:
    print("Something went wrong: ",err)
    
else:
    response = result.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response,'html.parser')
    
    print(soup.title)
    print(soup.title.string)
```

If i try to install bs4 using the commanda `pip3 install bs4` i get this messages:

```
Requirement already satisfied: bs4 in c:\users\gabri\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (0.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in c:\users\gabri\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from bs4) (4.9.3)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>1.2 in c:\users\gabri\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from beautifulsoup4->bs4) (2.2.1)
```

Não sei se isso ajuda de alguma forma mais o python 3.9 parece estar nesse caminho aqui

```
C:\Users\gabri\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.9
```

Segue uma foto de como está configuradas as variáveis de ambiente

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poderia esclarecer qual IDE está usando para programar?

Comment: Estou usando o Thonny e também tenho o pycharm instalado

Comment: Em relação ao pycharm isto pode ser a causa do problema, porque o pycharm utilizar um virtualenv para o projeto (ele não compartilha o env com o sistema operacional), desta forma como instalou no S.O. pode estar faltando instalar no "env" da IDE.

Comment: Mas eu estava usando somente o Thonny para rodar os códigos. O pycharm eu instalei e nem usei mais. A ideia seria desinstalar o pychamr? Eu consegui resolver o problema colocando o arquivo que queria rodar o código dentro da pasta que o bs4 está, mas isso não pareceu a melhor forma de resolver o problema

Comment: Não conheço o Thonny, não sei como funciona. Me desculpe.

Comment: quais versões do python estão instaladas no teu pc (há a versão 2.7 ou 3.6) alem da  3.9?

Comment: Todo ide, possui no setting ou em outra especificação a escolha de qual interpretador sera usado, pode ter acontecido estar usando um versão padrão e não a que você instalou as libs, atribuindo isso o retorno do erro, o ide pode estar usando uma versão diferente, se for isso apenas altere qual  interpretador sera usando.

Comment: Era bem próximo disso. A ide estava usando o sys.path das pastas erradas, dessa forma, ela tentava importar os módulos de pastas diferentes das que eles estavam instalados. Como sou bem recente em programação, não fazia nem ideia disso, então muito obrigado pelas ajudas pessoal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com a ajuda do @stack.cardoso eu consegui encontrar uma resposta. Basicamente a minha IDE estava buscando o modulo bs4 em um path diferente do que ele estava instalado. Para resolver isso eu mudei o path que minha IDE buscava as importações nas proprias configurações da IDE. Agora ela está sempre buscando nas mesmas pastas que o pip instala os módulos. Para descobrir qual o path que a IDE estava usando eu digitei no console da iDE:

```
import sys
for sys in sys.path:
    print(sys)
```

Answer (score -1):

Oi. Onde acho esse console, estou trabalhando com bs4 e dar erro, trabalhando com vscode, pelo terminal, e pasta PATH não acho, como busco? Ou que devo fazer

[Erro mensagem de from bs4 nao existe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHJbJ.png)

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

## Coletar a primeira página da lista de artistas

page = requests.get('https://web.archive.org/web/20121007172955/https://www.nga.gov/collection/anZ1.htm')

## Criar o objeto BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')